# CSS responsive div prevent cutting off with overflow hidden

Tags: css, responsive-design, overflow, aspect-ratio

I am using this layout for responsive div that maintains aspect ratio. It works well, but it requires `overflow: hidden`, to be clear it's `padding-top: 56.25%` defined in `:after`. If there is no overflow on wrapper, next element (in this case href link) is blocked.

My question is: is there a way to achieve same result without `overflow: hidden` on wrapper? I need some element to be visible outside wrapper without being cutting off.

Open snippet in full page if you can't see the issue within a small window.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-height: 383px;
  border: 1px solid;
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
}

#wrapper:after {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<a href="#">click me</a>
```

Comment: reduce the padding-top

Comment: Add whichever content you have in a wrapper div (like `.content`) you keep inside your `#wrapper` and place `.content` in `position: absolute;` - that should work for you.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Can you make a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a inner div and make it responsive with a pseudo element like you did before, and apply `overflow: hidden;` on it. Then add another sibling div and set the style you wish to apply, it would be div `#test` in the example, as you see it will be visible outside the wrapper.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#inner {
  min-width: 350px;
  max-height: 383px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#inner:after {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

#test {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner"></div>
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
<a href="#">click me</a>
```